# Change <td> background based on percentage in cell, as well as add '%' to number

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

Here's some easy reputation for someone.

### The scenario

I have a table that is built dynamically using JSP. There are several `<td>`'s that have a number in the cell representing a percentage. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/R3AUh/#base) for an example. I need to change the background color of the cell based on the percentage represented in the cell. For example:

```
value < 50 = Red
value >= 50 & < 90 = Yellow
value >= 90 = Green
```

In addition, I need the cell contents to be appended with the '%' sign. For example:

```
90 = 90%
```

### The Question

> How do I add a background-color based on the contents of the cell, and append text to it as well?

I have some jQuery I was going to use for this but it's not working at all. This too is in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/R3AUh/#base). I would also like it to be as lean as possible. If this can be done in a couple lines that would be great. **If it can be done purely with CSS that would be even better**, but I don't think that's possible.

### The Code

(if you don't like to follow links)

#### CSS

```css
.red {
    background-color: #f99;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #ff9;
}
.green {
    background-color: #9f9;
}
.notApplicable {
    background-color: #fff;
}
td.stopGapCondition {
    text-align: center;
}​
```

#### jQuery

```js
if ($('.stopGapCondition').text() < 50) {
    $('td .stopGapCondition').addClass('red');
}
if ($('.stopGapCondition').text() >= 50 && $('.stopGapCondition').text() < 90) {
    $('td .stopGapCondition').addClass('yellow');
}
if ($('.stopGapCondition').text() >= 90) {
    $('td .stopGapCondition').addClass('green');
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="content bordered" border="3" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" valign="top">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="stopGapTH" colspan="4">
            Patient List
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapTH" colspan="99">
            Clinical Adherence Information
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
          <th align="middle">
            Patient Name
          </th>
          <th align="middle">
            DOB
          </th>
          <th align="middle">
            Primary Disease
          </th>
          <th align="middle">
            Risk Index
          </th>
          <th>
            Athsma
          </th>
          <th>
            COPD
          </th>
          <th>
            Diabetes
          </th>
          <th>
            Heart Disease
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Louis Armstrong
          </td>
          <td>
            Blah
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition">
            50
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition">
            80
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition">
            75
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition">
            90
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Bob Barker
          </td>
          <td>
            Blah
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            49
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            89
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            90
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            David Brinkley
          </td>
          <td>
            1Blah
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Tom Brokaw
          </td>
          <td>
            10Blah4
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Cad2 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01Blah
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Cad3 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            0Blah
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Cad4 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            Blah5
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Cad5 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01Blah5
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Alex Trebek
          </td>
          <td>
            1Blah1
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Chucka Woolerya
          </td>
          <td>
            10Blah51
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Additionally, I forgot to mention that if it doesn't contain a number, meaning it could contain "na" or "n/a" or "not applicable", it should be white. I added the css but forgot to mention it in the question.  ​

Comment: you can add the % with css - td.stopGapCondition:after { content:"%"; }, not a JQuery programmer so cant help on that bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.each` to iterate the results; you can't apply one operation to them all at the same time.

```
$('.stopGapCondition').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.text();

    if(!/^\s*\d+(\.\d+)?\s*$/.test(value)) {
        $this.addClass('notApplicable');
        return;
    }

    if(value < 50) {
        $this.addClass('red');
    } else if(value < 90) {
        $this.addClass('yellow');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('green');
    }

    $this.text($this.text() + '%');
});​
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/R3AUh/15/)

Comment: @thepriebe: Actually, I didn't catch your update :P I have now, though.

Comment: @minitech Oddly, your recent update doesn't seem to work. It's just all white not. I think it's somehow defaulting on the `.notApplicable` class.

Comment: @thepriebe: Indeed it doesn't, I forgot to account for spaces. It *really* works now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.stopGapCondition').each(function(){
    var $cell= $(this), val=parseInt( $cell.text())|| null, color='notApplicable';
    color=(val && val<50) ? 'red': (( val>=50 && val <=90)? 'yellow': (( val>90)? 'green': 'notApplicable'));    
    $cell.addClass(color); 
    if(val) $cell.text( val +' %');   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R3AUh/18/

Comment: This is really pretty... It doesn't add the '%' but I love the shorthand if statement. That's awesome.

Comment: +1 for using parseInt, although you really should be [using a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with it: `val = parseInt($cell.text(), 10)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work : http://jsfiddle.net/R3AUh/10/

Answer (score 0):

Would the below code help. You can loop over the td with stopGapCondition class

```
 $("table td.stopGapCondition").each(function(e){


    if ($(this).text() < 50) {

        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
    if ($(this).text() >= 50 && $(this).text() < 90) {

        $(this).addClass('yellow');
    }
    if ($(this).text() >= 90) {

        $(this).addClass('green');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/R3AUh/19/

```
$('.stopGapCondition').each(function() {

    switch(true) {
        case ($(this).text() < 50 && $(this).text() !== ''):
            $(this).addClass('red');
            break;
        case ($(this).text() >= 50 && $(this).text() < 90):
            $(this).addClass('yellow');
            break;
        case ($(this).text() >= 90):
            $(this).addClass('green');
            break;
    }
});
```