# AJAX/jQuery: Change DIV background based on number value in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am new with AJAX/jQuery and trying something new.

[here is my fiddle for better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/jbke9un2/) Each of those squares are DIVS.

```
<div class="desk_box_ver" id="desk_B20" data-rel="85" style="left:20px;top:1165px;">B20</div>
```

The number inside of is being retrieved with an AJAX call that GETs it with a PHP script executing 
a query, it will replace the "B20" for "1300" as an example.

**Problem:**

How can I produce a "heat map" based on the numbers being displayed.
Example: Lets say the number range is from 100(the lowest) to 1800(the highest).
Depending on the number range, a background color will have to be displayed from
green-ish, to yellow-ish, orange-ish, and red.

A similar problem I found on stackoverflow is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508325/change-td-background-based-on-percentage-in-cell-as-well-as-add-to-number)

**AJAX:how I am displaying the numbers inside of the DIVs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{  } , // do I need to pass data if im GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                            var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                            if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
```

THIS IS WHERE I AM OUTPUTTING THE NUMBER

```
      divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']); // set inner HTML with AHT value


                            }//end if
                            }//end for
                      }//end success
                });//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

**show_aht.php numbers being retrieved from the array below**

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
    // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) 
    $userdata = $user[$username];
    //if AHT is null give N/A as value
    if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => 'NA',
                                             'station'  => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end inner if 
    //else give the actual value of AHT without the decimals
    else {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => substr($memodata['aht_value'],0,-3),
                                             'station'   => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end else
    }//end outer if
    }//end for

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your fiddle

Comment: @SimonH whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a play with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotbelgo/yp6gghz6/). It inserts a value and then applies a color to is (using a very simple algorithm that you will want to change). Here's how you could implement it in your code

```
success : function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
    var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
    if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
       divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));
    }//end if
  }//end for
}//end success
```

Make these available in your code:

```
function colorMe(v){
    return "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
}

function conv(x){
    return Math.floor((x - 100) / (1800-100) * 255);
}
```

Comment: this gives it random colors. What I'd like to have is starting from green all the way to red. How may I do this? thanks

Comment: would you mind if we go on chat? I'd really like to know how I can incorporate your solution to my code. the way the color changes is exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: thanks a lot ! It really works! would you mind explaining how I can set my lowest and highest value ? thanks!

Comment: Made small edit to show how I incorporated you 100 and 1800 in conv

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot appreciate your help! was going around in circles with hard code. your code is simple and clever!

Comment: something I forgot to mention I'm doing this in case my "aht_value" is "NA" (null value) then Ill want to background to be white.. this is what I tried but doesnt work. **if(data[i]['aht_value'] == "NA")
                divForResult.html(numberr).css("background-color", "white"));
               else
               divForResult.html(numberr).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));**  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem completely, but here is the simplest possible idea to hopefully help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/Arministrator/0vhv37jf/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var valuediv = document.getElementById('valuediv');
    var valuedive = valuediv.innerHTML;
    $("#valuediv").css({"background-color":"#"+valuedive});
});
```

Whatever number is inside a div it will affect the color of the div. You can play with it if you want more than 3 digits, this is just an example to guide you. (For example #900 is red color)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a generic function that takes a number and a range object as arguments, and calculates a color for the number based on its position in the range.

```
/**
 * Calculate a color based on number's position in a range.
 * @param  {number} num  Number to calculate a color for
 * @param  {object} opts Range of colors and numbers in the following form:
 *                       {
 *                          start: {number: {number}, color: {rgb array: [r,g,b]}},
 *                          end:   {number: {number}, color: {rgb array: [r,g,b]}}
 *                       }
 *                       where each of "r", "g", "b" is a value from 0 to 255.
 *                       I.e. a range specifying numbers from 0 to 100 with colors from black to white: {start: {number: 0, color: [0,0,0]}, end: {number: 100, color: [255,255,255]}}
 * @return {string}      CSS color
 */
function colorCode(num, opts) {
    var color = [];

    if(num <= opts.start.number)
        color = opts.start.color;
    else if(num >= opts.end.number)
        color = opts.end.color;
    else {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            color[i] = Math.round( (num - opts.start.number) / (opts.end.number - opts.start.number) * (opts.end.color[i] - opts.start.color[i]) + opts.start.color[i] );
        }
    }

    return 'rgb(' + color.join() + ')';
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tikosar/d0uwsw48/)

Comment: nice code, so if I'd want to call the function colorCode in IF statement would I call it like so? **divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorCode(data[i]['aht_value'],data[i]['aht_value'] ));** since the parameters is twice the number value? If I understood correctly. thanks

Comment: Not quite, @alda1234 .
"`colorCode`" accepts a number as the first parameter (you were right on that one), but the second parameter must be an object.
Please, see the jsdoc explanation before the function. I've also included an example usage there.